# Creating objects from dynamic JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have written some code to create JPanels dynamically.   I now need a way to capture the data that the user creates in these JPanels.  I currently have a "create" button.  When fired, I want this button to create an object using the 3 different data types in each panel: name(String), count(int), and a boolean.

I am pretty raw at programming, but the major hurdle I am facing is how to I access dynamic objects that are not named like these panels?  I figured out how to add and remove them, but I can't figure out the methods to capture data from the fields in the panes.

Thanks, the code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


public class MainSnakeGUI {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new MainSnakeGUI();
    }

    public MainSnakeGUI() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Create the frame
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake Channels");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new SnakePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SnakePane extends JPanel {
        public SnakePane() {
            //Create buttons and labels
            JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add New Snake");
            JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Delete Snake");
            JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("Create a Split Snake");
            JButton btnCreate = new JButton("Create");
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            //Create JPanels
            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            JPanel header = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            JPanel footer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            //add items to JPanels
            buttons.add(btnAdd);
            buttons.add(btnRemove);
            header.add(headerLabel);
            footer.add(btnCreate);
            //add JPanels to window
            add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);  //sets header at the top of window
            header.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
            add(buttons, BorderLayout.BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS);  //sets the button to the left of the display pane
            buttons.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
            add(footer, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);  //sets buttons on the bottom of window
            footer.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));


            //add panel to hold new frames
            final JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            content.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

            //add scroll pane?
            add(new JScrollPane(content));

            //add listener for button
            btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SplitSnakeCreationPane pane = new SplitSnakeCreationPane();  //create a new SnakeCreationPane
                    int insertAt = Math.max(0, content.getComponentCount() - 1);  //insert it at the end of the list
                    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    gbc.weightx = 1;
                    content.add(pane, gbc, insertAt);  //add the pane to the window
                    content.revalidate();
                    content.repaint();
                }
            });

            btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int paneCount = content.getComponentCount()-1;  //get count of the pane
                    content.remove(content.getComponent(paneCount-1));  //remove the pane at paneCount
                    content.revalidate();  //update window with changes
                    content.repaint();
                    SplitSnakeCreationPane.snakeCount--;  //update count for snakes
                }
            });

            btnCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int paneCount = content.getComponentCount()-1;  //get count of the pane
                    for (int i=0; i<paneCount;){

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //set size of window
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(1200, 400);
        }
    }

    public static class SplitSnakeCreationPane extends JPanel {
        //Count of how many snakes created
        private static int snakeCount = 1;

        public SplitSnakeCreationPane() {

            //creates Snake Panes
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 4, 10, 10));
            add(new JLabel("Split Snake " + (snakeCount++) + "."));
            add(new JLabel("Snake Name"));
            add(new JLabel("Channel Count"));
            add(new JLabel(""));
            add(new JLabel(""));
            JTextField snakeName =  new JTextField(30);
            JTextField channelCount = new JTextField("0",3);
            JCheckBox artistSupplied = new JCheckBox("Artist Supplied?");
            add(snakeName); //Snake Name field
            add(channelCount);  //Channel Count field
            add(artistSupplied); //Artist supplied checkbox
            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *create an object using the 3 different data types in each panel* I couldnt get this

Comment: I can hardly understand the question.

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing, I will attempt to clarify.  

If you run the program, you will see it creates a large pane with 3 buttons: "add, delete, and create".   When you click add, it creates a smaller pane with 2 text fields and a check box.  Each time you click add, it adds a new pane with those 3 fields.   I want to capture the user input from these text fields and check boxes.   

Since these Jpanels are dynamic, they are not declared in the code, and I don't know enough to figure out how to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting those fields as local variables in the constructor, You need use class variables in your SplitSnakeCreationPane and then add a public get method to get the values from those fields. As long as you have those get method, you can use it to get filed value anywhere you need.

see the modified class as follows:

```
public static class SplitSnakeCreationPane extends JPanel {
        //Count of how many snakes created
        private static int snakeCount = 1;

        private JTextField snakeName = null;
        private JTextField channelCount = null;        
        private JCheckBox artistSupplied = null;

        public SplitSnakeCreationPane() {

            //creates Snake Panes
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 4, 10, 10));
            add(new JLabel("Split Snake " + (snakeCount++) + "."));
            add(new JLabel("Snake Name"));
            add(new JLabel("Channel Count"));
            add(new JLabel(""));
            add(new JLabel(""));
            snakeName =  new JTextField(30);
            channelCount = new JTextField("0",3);
            artistSupplied = new JCheckBox("Artist Supplied?");
            add(snakeName); //Snake Name field
            add(channelCount);  //Channel Count field
            add(artistSupplied); //Artist supplied checkbox
            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        }

        public String getSnakeName() {
            return snakeName.getText();
        }

        public String getChannelCount() {
            return channelCount.getText();
        }

        public boolean getArtistSupplied() {
            return artistSupplied.isSelected();
        }
    }
```

Here is the complete code, copy paste and give it a run: result will be printed on the console. hope You can get the idea on how to get those values

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


public class MainSnakeGUI {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new MainSnakeGUI();
    }

    public MainSnakeGUI() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Create the frame
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake Channels");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new SnakePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SnakePane extends JPanel {


        public SnakePane() {
            //Create buttons and labels
            JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add New Snake");
            JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Delete Snake");
            JButton show = new JButton("show value");
            JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("Create a Split Snake");
            JButton btnCreate = new JButton("Create");
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            //Create JPanels
            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            JPanel header = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            JPanel footer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            //add items to JPanels
            buttons.add(btnAdd);
            buttons.add(btnRemove);
            buttons.add(show);
            header.add(headerLabel);
            footer.add(btnCreate);
            //add JPanels to window
            add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);  //sets header at the top of window
            header.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
            add(buttons, BorderLayout.BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS);  //sets the button to the left of the display pane
            buttons.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
            add(footer, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);  //sets buttons on the bottom of window
            footer.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));


            //add panel to hold new frames
            final JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            content.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

            //add scroll pane?
            add(new JScrollPane(content));

            //add listener for button
            btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SplitSnakeCreationPane pane = new SplitSnakeCreationPane();  //create a new SnakeCreationPane
                    int insertAt = Math.max(0, content.getComponentCount() - 1);  //insert it at the end of the list
                    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    gbc.weightx = 1;
                    content.add(pane, gbc, insertAt);  //add the pane to the window

                    System.out.println(insertAt);
                    content.revalidate();
                    content.repaint();
                }
            });

            btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int paneCount = content.getComponentCount()-1;  //get count of the pane
                    content.remove(content.getComponent(paneCount-1));  //remove the pane at paneCount
                    content.revalidate();  //update window with changes
                    content.repaint();
                    SplitSnakeCreationPane.snakeCount--;  //update count for snakes
                }
            });


            show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    for(int n=0; n<content.getComponentCount(); n++){

                        if(content.getComponent(n) instanceof SplitSnakeCreationPane){

                            SplitSnakeCreationPane com = (SplitSnakeCreationPane) content.getComponent(n);

                            System.out.println("Sname Name is : " + com.getSnakeName());
                            System.out.println("ChannelCount is : " + com.getChannelCount());
                            System.out.println("ArtistSupplied  is : " + com.getArtistSupplied());
                        }


                    }



                }
            });


            btnCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int paneCount = content.getComponentCount()-1;  //get count of the pane
                    for (int i=0; i<paneCount;){

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //set size of window
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(1200, 400);
        }
    }

    public static class SplitSnakeCreationPane extends JPanel {
        //Count of how many snakes created
        private static int snakeCount = 1;

        private JTextField snakeName = null;
        private JTextField channelCount = null;        
        private JCheckBox artistSupplied = null;

        public SplitSnakeCreationPane() {

            //creates Snake Panes
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 4, 10, 10));
            add(new JLabel("Split Snake " + (snakeCount++) + "."));
            add(new JLabel("Snake Name"));
            add(new JLabel("Channel Count"));
            add(new JLabel(""));
            add(new JLabel(""));
            snakeName =  new JTextField(30);
            channelCount = new JTextField("0",3);
            artistSupplied = new JCheckBox("Artist Supplied?");
            add(snakeName); //Snake Name field
            add(channelCount);  //Channel Count field
            add(artistSupplied); //Artist supplied checkbox
            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        }

        public String getSnakeName() {
            return snakeName.getText();
        }

        public String getChannelCount() {
            return channelCount.getText();
        }

        public boolean getArtistSupplied() {
            return artistSupplied.isSelected();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense and is an excellent extension of what I was going for in creating these panes.  However, I am used to a constructor creating an object using a name I provide.  Then I can access that name with the get method, I.E. mainSnake1.getSnakeName

What do i do when the program creates the objects dynamically?  I don't know how they are referenced, so how do I know which pane I am calling the getter on?

Comment: Hi I updated the answer, please have a look and try the second pieces of code again. good luck

Comment: Sweet, This works, and I think I can use it to scale the program to do what I want.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create your own custom action listener:

```
public class CustomListener extends ActionListener {

    private List<SplitSnakeCreationPane> allPanes = new ArrayList<SplitSnakeCreationPane>();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Create your pane
    //Add that pane to your 'allPanes' list.
    }

    public List<SplitSnakeCreationPane> getAllPanes(){
        return this.allPanes;
    }

}
```

Now you create an object of this class and add that to the button:

```
CustomListener createListener = new CustomListener();
btnCreate.addActionListener(createListener);
```

Now if you wish to retrieve the panes you added, just call:

```
List<SplitSnakeCreationPane> allPanes = createListener.getAllPanes();
```

Comment: Good luck! Just start with creating the custom listener and make it save a list of anything that is created when you click on `create`. So just `allPanes.add(yourNewPane);` The `getAllPanes` method should then give you a list of all panes and each pane is a reference to an existing pane, so you can call `allPanes.get(0).getChildren()` or something like that on it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.

I feel like this is the right answer, but I am still confused as to how to implement it.  

This method is going to create a list of the panes WHEN I press "create", correct?  I would then be able to use the list to reference each individual pane by its place in the list.  OK, the more I think about it,  the more it makes sense.  I will play with this, and let you know if I get stuck.

Comment: The list is already there, just empty. Whenever you click the `create` button, add the pane your created to that list. All of that is done in the `actionPerformed` method of course. Each time you click `create` a pane will be added to the list. At any time you can call the `getAllPanes()` method and it will give you all panes created up until that point. I'm off to bed, good luck!